# SQL query to update value in table to sum of attribute in another table, where the ID's match

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I have tried several different queries and cannot seem to find one that works without causing an error

> Incorrect syntax near keyword '  '

I have one table called `Scores` that saves the userID, week number, and that weeks score from a quiz.

Schema:

- Scores (Id, userName, weekNumber, currentScore)

There are 12 weeks total, so in the end each user will have 12 entries in this table

I have another table `Leaderboard` that has schema :

- Leaderboard (Id, userName, week1, week2, week3 ..... week12, totalScore)

Each user will only have one entry in this table.

I have been trying to save the sum of the currentScore from Scores into the totalScore attribute of Leaderboard and cannot seem to figure out the correct syntax.

My query is as follows:

```
UPDATE t1
SET t1.totalScore = t2.completeScore
FROM dbo.Leaderboard AS t1,
     ((SELECT Id, SUM(weeklyScore) AS completeScore FROM dbo.Scores) as F 
      INNER JOIN 
          (SELECT Id FROM dbo.Scores GROUP BY Id) AS S ON F.Id = S.Id) AS t2
WHERE t1.Id = t2.Id
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this and let us know how it goes:

```
var total1 = ("UPDATE t1 " +
        "SET t1.totalScore = t2.completeScore " +
        "FROM dbo.Leaderboard AS t1, (SELECT F.Id, F.completeScore FROM " + 
        "(SELECT Id, SUM(weeklyScore) AS completeScore FROM dbo.Scores GROUP BY ID) as F " +
        "INNER JOIN (SELECT Id FROM dbo.Scores/* GROUP BY Id*/) AS S "+
        "ON F.Id = S.Id) AS t2 "+
        "WHERE t1.Id = t2.Id");
```

By the way I think you were missing a `GROUP BY` clause in the definition of the `F` derived table and that you don't need the `GROUP BY` in the definition of the `S` derived table.

Comment: Yeah I see what you mean by the GROUP BY clause not being needed in S but in F instead. I tried that query and the error I received was "The column 'Id' was specified multiple times for t2'.

Comment: Instead of `SELECT *` select the columns you need from F and S derived tables.